# How to save images from template in django

Tags: django-views

I wanted to save image to profile's image field from template, but I'm not able to save in media root

```
class SettingFormView(FormView):
    form_class = ProfileSettingsForm
    template_name = 'profile.html'
    success_url = '/'

    def get_initial(self):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            profile = Profile.objects.get(user_id__exact=self.request.user.id)
            self.initial['first_name'] = profile.first_name
            self.initial['last_name'] = profile.last_name
            self.initial['fathers_name'] = profile.fathers_name
            self.initial['email'] = profile.email
            self.initial['mobile'] = profile.mobile
            self.initial['entity'] = profile.entity
            self.initial['image'] = profile.image
        return self.initial.copy()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            form = ProfileSettingsForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
            user = User.objects.get(username__exact=self.request.user.username)
            if form:
                profile = Profile.objects.get(user_id__exact=self.request.user.id)
                profile.first_name = self.request.POST['first_name']
                profile.last_name = self.request.POST['last_name']
                profile.fathers_name = self.request.POST['fathers_name']
                if user.email != self.request.POST['email']:
                    profile.email = self.request.POST['email']
                    user.email = self.request.POST['email']
                profile.mobile = self.request.POST['mobile']
                profile.entity = self.request.POST['entity']
                profile.image = self.request.POST['image']
                **profile.image.async = self.request.POST['image']**
                profile.save()
                user.save()
                return super(SettingFormView, self).form_valid(form)
        else:
            return redirect('/profile/sign')
```

I get the following exception:

> Exception Type:   MultiValueDictKeyError Exception Value: "'image'"

Answer (score 0):

Uploaded files are in `request.FILES`, not `request.POST`. Alos take a lok at the [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads).

#### 'Plain' version

```
f = request.FILES['image']
with open('upload/destination.ext', 'wb+') as dest:
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        dest.write(chunk)
```

#### Model version

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files-with-a-model)

```
profile_form = ProfileSettingsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if profile_form.is_valid():
        profile = Profile(image=request.FILES['image'])
        profile.first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
        # ...
        profile.save()
```

Comment: what about this field, and if  i will use filefield could i use it in template as image?

Comment: About `ImageField` - see edited answer. `ImageField` is an extension of `FileField`. To handle images you should use the `ImageField`.

Comment: it gives errorException Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value: "'image'"

Comment: please edit your qustion and add your code for form and models. the error means that you *don't* have a file named 'image' in your request. and how does your form tag look like? do you use `multipart/form-data`?